# how use Image::make Laravel parse in ftp server using Storage

Tags: laravel, ftp, ftp-server

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARl76.png]`

My Problem is the upload image laravel still error.
Internal server error, IDK where is wrong in my code 
I'm using FTP cause it should be upload to external storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image intervention `stream()` facade used for upload image:

http://image.intervention.io/api/stream

```
$getFile = Image::make($request->file('image')->path())->resize(320, 240);
$image_thumb = $getFile->stream();
Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filenametostore, $image_thumb->__toString());
```